# Why is Rails before_filter called twice when the controller is subclassed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, actioncontroller, before-filter

I'm at Rails 2.3.5 and I have this problem:

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :foo, :only => [:index]
end

class ChildController < BaseController
  before_filter :foo, :only => [:index, :show, :other, :actions]
end
```

The problem is that on ChildController, the :foo before filter gets called twice.

I've tried a number of workarounds around this problem. If I don't include the `:index` action in the child, it never gets called for that action.

The solution I found works, but I think it's very very ugly

```
skip_before_filter :foo
before_filter :foo, :only => [:index, :show, :other, :actions]
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"This behavior is by design".

The Rails guide on controllers states:

"Filters are inherited, so if you set a filter on ApplicationController, it will be run on every controller in your application."

This explains the behaviour you're seeing. It also suggests the exact same solution you propose (using skip_before_filter) to define which filters will or will not be run for a particular controller and/or methods.

So, ugly or not, seems like the solution you found is common and approved practice.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `skip_before_filter` you could always skip the `index` action in the `ChildController`:

```
class ChildController < BaseController
  before_filter :foo, :only => [:show, :other, :actions]
end
```

But this might become a problem if you change the behavior in `BaseController` and remove the filter from the `index` action. Then it would never be called so using `skip_before_filter` might be a better idea.